# Validate multiple query params using Valdiate method Nuxt 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to validate query params before entering the page in nuxt js 2.

There are 2 query params I wanted to validate using [Validate](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/components-glossary/validate/)

```
  validate({ params, query, store, app }) {

    if (query.field && query.field !== "1" || query.field && query.field !== '2') {
      throw new Error('error')
    }

   else if(query.company){

 app.$axios.get('/api/company-check/' + query.company).then(res => {
      if (res.data.success) {
        return true;

      } else {
        return false
      }
    });
}
  },
```

I tried the above method to validate the `field` and `company` The validation only works in the first statement only.

I'm not sure what's done wrong here. any help is appreciated

Comment: So, if the first statement is falsy, it stops and never reaches the second?

Comment: @kissu yea :\ .

Comment: You could rewrite it thanks to `includes` or maybe add more parenthesis between the 2 statements.